# Putting text in mysql database using tinymce and php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor for writing the text into the database using php. Whenever I am writing anything into the editor using keyboard then the code works absolutely fine. But whenever I copy and paste lorem ipsum text into the tinymce editor then I am getting a syntax error and the database is not getting updated.

following shows the syntax error which of course in not going to be helpful. But still for completing the post I am showing the syntax error related to mysql that I am getting while adding something to the database using tinymce.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">It is a long established fa' at line 1
```

Comment: you have to add your variable inside `mysql_real_escape_string()`;

Comment: @Bhavik Thanks genius.

Answer (score -1):

remove all double quotes from string then try it

Comment: The solution provided by @Bhavik is perfect and works absolutely fine